# How do I create this graph to show a whole sphere spiral and not just half?

Tags: plotting

This is what I am inputting into Mathematica and I can only see the top half of the spherical spiral 
`ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t]Sin[t/30],Sin[t/30]Sin[t/30],Cos[t/30]},{t,0,30}]`

Comment: `ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] Sin[t/30], Sin[t/30] Sin[t/30], 
  Cos[t/30]}, {t, 0, 30 2 \[Pi]}]`?

Comment: You should ask this in the comment in your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] Sin[t/a], Sin[t] Sin[t/a], Cos[t/a]}, {t, 0,
    a Pi}], {a, Range[10, 50, 10]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you!